# File creation date

Tags: files

I have a function in template.php:

```
function test_file_icon($variables) {
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = drupal_get_path('theme', 'test') . '/images/icons';

  $mime = check_plain($file->filemime);
  $icon_url = file_icon_url($file, $icon_directory);
  return '<div class="file-icon"><img alt="" class="file-icon" src="' . $icon_url . '" title="' . $mime . '" /></div>';

}
```

and at the end of file icon i want to show date of file create. Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `format_date($file->timestamp)` somewhere to html of the return value. To set the proper time format, see the documentation of [format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7).

```
return '<div class="file-icon"><img alt="" class="file-icon" src="' . $icon_url . '" title="' . $mime . '" /> ' . format_date($file->timestamp) . ' </div>';
```